Pass templated base class generic child to function without restricting by the template type
I have the following problem. I want to create a baseclass with variable type property that is used internally by the base class and classes that inherit from it as follows:
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    protected T Value { get; set; }//Not used outside of the inheriting classes
    public abstract byte[] ToBinary();
}
public class MyClass1 : BaseClass<int>
{
    public override byte[] ToBinary()
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(Value);//We use the templated property internally here
    }
}
public class MyClass2 : BaseClass<string>
{
    public override byte[] ToBinary()
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Value);
    }
}

The problem arises when I would like to write a function that wants to use any child of the baseclass (MyClass1 or MyClass2) without accessing the templated information from the outside as follows:
//Compiler requires us to provide the type for the BaseClass here
//We want to be able to pass multiple different BaseClass inheriting child types here
//f.e. MyClass1 and MyClass2 without restricting the usage to specific template type
public static void DoSomethingWithAnyClassInheritingBase(BaseClass b) {
    //This implementation should not matter to us and we are not using the
    //Templated params outside of this class
    b.ToBinary();//Always returns binary and takes no arguments
}
    

How could I get around this kind of problem?

Have some interface define this ToBinary() and change parameter type to that interface.

public interface IBinaryConverter 
{
   byte[] ToBinary();
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBinaryConverter
{
    protected T Value { get; set; }//Not used outside of the inheriting classes
    public abstract byte[] ToBinary();
}
public class MyClass1 : BaseClass<int>
{
    public override byte[] ToBinary()
    {
        //We use the templated property internally here
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(Value);
    }
}

public class MyClass2 : BaseClass<string>
{
    public override byte[] ToBinary()
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Value);
    }
}

public static void DoSomethingWithAnyClassInheritingBase(IBinaryConverter b) {
    //This implementation should not matter to us and we are not using the
    //Templated params outside of this class
    b.ToBinary();//Always returns binary and takes no arguments
}

The problem is the root dependency is that you have defined BaseClass<T> without a BaseClass non generic. You could define it as an interface as above or you could equally include a non generic definition as follows if you don't want to use an interface:

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract byte[] ToBinary();
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    protected T Value { get; set; }//Not used outside of the inheriting classes
}

You would then be able to implement BaseClass but still pass instances of it to the DoSomethingWithAnyClassInheritingBase function.
